# Replace Mathematical Symbols in File

Tags: python, string, math, replace

I have a file which contains some mathematical expressions in latex form. For example, I have the following which appears in my file:

```
{\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}{r}}}\zeta
```

I would like to write a python code which will scan the file and output a new file where all the instances of the above expression are replaced with

```
\zeta''
```

I have tried the following code:

```
    import sys
    import fileinput

    for line in fileinput.input():
    l = line.replace(r"{\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}{r}}}\zeta","\zeta'")
    sys.stdout = open('output.txt','a')
    sys.stdout.write(l)
```

I know that the r which appears just before the first string to be replaced tells the code to ignore any escape characters. But it appears to have difficulty dealing with the d^{2} part. This "^" symbol is not correctly interpreted by the code, so it doesn't make the replacement.

I know that {\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}{r}}}\zeta is not technically a string, but I'm not sure how else to treat it. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a string? What is it then?

Comment: I don't know what it would be classified as. Maybe it is a string, but I don't know how to get the code to deal with the ^ symbol...

Comment: Well, as far as I know it's a string. I was wondering if you knew something different. There's nothing special about the `^` symbol in this context, it's just a character in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent of your code (regex.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import fileinput

x = open("output.txt", "a")

for line in fileinput.input():
    l = line.replace(r"{\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}{r}}}\zeta","\zeta''")
    x.write(l)
```

Seems to run just fine: `$ echo '{\frac{d^{2}}{d^{2}{r}}}\zeta' | ./regex.py` gives:

`\zeta''`

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you talk me through what you changed, and if you have any idea why the previous code wasn't working?

Comment: All I did was that I changed reading to reading from stdin, and I print the output to stdout. I also formatted your for-loop correctly - you need the indentation. That's all.

Comment: Is there anyway to preserve the ability to specify the input and output files? Thanks for pointing out the indentation problem, that was a mistake in my question, but wasn't in my code.

Comment: doing `for line in fileinput.input()` works fine too

Comment: so perhaps the problem is in the way you're trying to write output... for example you are opening the file every time you read a line and I'm not sure how correct is doing `sys.stdout = open(...)` in python... it seems suspicious.

Comment: I updated the snippet to support input and output files

Comment: Yes, thanks. You're right, the rest of the code is fine. Thanks for your help!